# JPA 2.0 is not showing the tables in the schema in myEclipse professional 2013

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa-2.0, myeclipse

I want to generate entity classes from database tables through JPA, i have made a new driver in the myeclipse and after creating a connection with it in database explorer, all the tables are showing in the dbo schema but the problem is when i try to create entities from tables through JPA, i cant see the tables of which i want to create entity. In table list JPA is showing the tables which are not even in the DBO Schema.
Please help me out
[image]

I want to create entity class for project table but its not showing, however in db browser it is showing.
I am using myEclipse professional 2013 and jpa 2.0, database is sql server 2008 ,jdk 1.6 and jdbc driver is sqljdbc4.jar

Comment: Could be a missunderstanding between schema and database?

Comment: @bra_racing could be, but now what should i do

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem, when you are creating a EJBProject, when giving datasource name, give the detail about database connection at that time and select override default catalog from connection to be pointed at your database and same for the schema

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a wizard that isn't part of MyEclipse but part of some DALI support which should be turned off in MyEclipse, as those functions are supplied by MyEclipse. Right click on the project and select "Generate Entities and DAOs" to generate your entities. Full details [here](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/persistence/myeclipse-jpa-tutorial/#3_Reverse_Engineer_a_Database_Table).

Check in Window/Preferences/General/Capabilities then Advanced/MyEclipse Standard Tools and make sure the "DALI Deprecated" option is not selected (do the same for other deprecated or "Leave Off" options). If you've installed some DALI plugins separately, I suggest you remove them.

Comment: i have done it through the default JPA 2.0 wizard that comes with myEclipse professional 2013 and done the same as i have mentioned in my answer.